# Python setuptools: How to define installation time conditional dependencies for dist package?

Tags: python, cross-platform, mysql-python, setuptools, pymysql

I make dist packeges of my module, which depends on `MySQL-python`. I realized, that some users don't have MySQL installed, and therefore it's easier for them to install `pymysql` (python based client) as a dependency, then install MySQL itself. The latter is especially difficult on Mac, as I heard. First I put a conditional statement in my `setup.py`, to check for MySQL executables, and if those are available, then attach `MySQL-python` to `install_requires` list, else append `pymysql`. Then I realized, that `setup.py` runs on my machine if I build dist package, however I should check availability of MySQL on the user's system. My question is that how is it possible? If it is entirely impossible to do this in case of a dist package, is it possible to tell `pip` to accept either `MySQL-python` or `pymysql` as a valid dependency? And maybe try to install the former, and fallback to the latter?

Comment: If they *do* have MySQL, is there a problem with installing `pymysql` alongside it?

Comment: no, there is no problem with that. I just guess that MySQL-python might have better performance (i am not sure), and why install an additional module in case it's not necessary.